# Como subir archivo XML a google drive con PHP

Tags: php, api, xml, php8, drive

Tengo un problema, ya que estoy intentando hacer un formulario para subir archivos a Google Drive con la API para PHP, pero al momento de subir un XML lo sube vacío y no se que pueda estar pasando, ya repase el código varias veces pero no veo el error, al subir una imagen no hay problema, solo con xml. Adjunto el código que utilizo para realizar la subida

try{

```
    $service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);

    //instacia de archivo
    $file = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();
    $file->setName($documento);

    //id de la carpeta donde hemos dado el permiso a la cuenta de servicio 
    $file->setParents(array($claveJSON));
    $file->setDescription($descripcion);
    $file->setMimeType("text/xml");

    $result = $service->files->create(
      $file,
      array(
        'data' => file_get_contents($documento),
        'mimeType' => $mime_type,
        'uploadType' => 'multipart'
      )
    );
    /* FICHERO SUBIDO A GOOGLE DRIVE */
    echo '2.- Fichero subido a Google Drive.';
}catch(Google_Service_Exception $gs){
    $m=json_decode($gs->getMessage());
    echo $m->error->message;
}catch(Exception $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
  
}
```

Espero puedan apoyarme a resolverlo. Saludos!

Comment: Y, ¿qué contenido tiene el XML que estás creando?

Comment: Prueba con `$file->setMimeType("text/plain");`